# Datatables using JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, datatables

I have been stuck for days on this issue. I am trying to pull data into my datatable for an inventory system using JSON data. I for some reason cannot get my In Inventory column to display the number of items left. The data is being pulled from my JSON file located at http://lungavitadesigns.com/api/inventory_list.php

The datatable is located at http://lungavitadesigns.com/inventory.php

Below is the code I am using to populate the data. Any help is highly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    $('#inventory').DataTable( {
  columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: [ 0, 1, 2 ,3,4]
                }
        ],
        "scrollY":        "700px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         false,
  
   dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],
        "ajax": 'http://lungavitadesigns.com/api/inventory_list.php',
  "columns": [
   {
      "data": "master_image.url",
      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
       return '<img src="'+data+'" width="100px" height="100px" />';
    }
   },

            {"data": "name"},
   {
    data: 'variations.0.price_money.amount',
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
     return '$'+ data;
    }
   },
   {data: "inventory.quantity_on_hand"},
   {"data": "available_online"}
   
   
        ],
  
 
  
    });   
 
  
 } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response is missing `inventory` and `inventory.quantity_on_hand` properties for each row.

[image: Screenshot]